# Getting Header error in JMeter when trying to get HTML report

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to get the HTML report from my JMeter test plan. Unfortunately, below error is shown always.

```
File '/Users/roradhak/Cisco/GET/PPS-Proxy-Performance/Graph2_CSV.csv' does not contain the field names header, ensure the jmeter.save.saveservice.* properties are the same as when the CSV file was created or the file may be read incorrectly
```

In fact, I tried to do all the settings changes as explained in [Jmeter 3.0 can't generate the ANT HTML report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41102508/jmeter-3-0-cant-generate-the-ant-html-report) and in other links also. Can someone please put some light into this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure you have at least the following line in *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true
```

The first line of your .jtl results file needs to be like:

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
```

If you have different output - kindly amend JMeter configuration to match the one, described in the [Generating Report Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) article.

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: I can confirm that jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true was already set in my properties file. When you say .jtl file, i am not generating a .jtl file. I am creating a .csv file from aggregate report and that report is given as an input for HTML report using command line. Still no good :(

Comment: `jtl`== `csv`, don't use Aggregate Report output, [run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like `jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl` and generate reporting dashboard like `jmeter -g result.jtl -o /report/destination/folder`

Comment: You made my day. Fantastic!!! Its working great. The command line usage instead of using the aggregate report did the work.

Comment: Dmitri.. One last thing... I have given Threads as 500 and Forever count as 10. But when i run the command line, i could see number of samples as only 10. Why is that? I am expecting 5000 samples.

Comment: jtl== csv, don't use Aggregate Report output, run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode like jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl and generate reporting dashboard like jmeter -g result.jtl -o /report/destination/folder – Dmitri T Mar 6 '17 at 16:35 
This literally saved than reading the question and what not

Comment: I was setting `jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format` to `xml`. Now I change it to be `csv`. All good.