# Not able to generate html report in JMeter using Commandline

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to generate html report from the csv file that is created. I am using BlazeMeter to record the test which gives me .jmx file.

When I give:
sh jmeter -n -t /home/Annie/JMeter/vDC1.jmx -l /home/Annie/JMeter/a.csv
I am getting a csv file where there is no header.So when trying to generate a html report it shows:
File '/home/Annie/JMeter/a.csv' does not contain the field names header, ensure the jmeter.save.saveservice.* properties are the same as when the CSV file was created or the file may be read incorrectly.

I tried the solution found in:
[Getting Header error in JMeter when trying to get HTML report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629732/getting-header-error-in-jmeter-when-trying-to-get-html-report)

Its still showing the same error. However its showing the html report.
Is there anything else to be  done?

Comment: my user.properties file did not contain
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true so I added the line.

Comment: Did you tried update the line in jmeter.properties?

Comment: yeah...its giving the same message as above . However in the csv file it leaves the first line empty. Earlier the data got populated from the first line itself.